# Rails Link_to image tag isnt retrieving image from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm brand new to rails (and coding in general) so I've a quick question on retrieving images from a database

Running rails 3.2.8

I have a list of products, code, description, price and product_image in the database, The product images is stored as 123.jpg in the database and the image itself is stored in app/assets/images folder

In my view I have the following code

```
    <div class="center_content">

<div class="center_title_bar">Latest Products</div>

            <% @camera_catalogues.each do |camera_catalogue| %>

    <div class="prod_box">
        <div class="top_prod_box"></div>
        <div class="center_prod_box">            
             <div class="product_title"><a href="details.html"><%= camera_catalogue.model_description %></a></div>
             <div class="product_img"><a href="details.html"><%= link_to (image_tag camera_catalogue.product_image),camera_catalogue %></a></div>
             <div class="prod_price"><span class="reduce">350$</span> <span class="price"><%=number_to_currency(camera_catalogue.price, :unit =>"&euro;")%> </span></div>                        
        </div>
        <div class="bottom_prod_box"></div>             
        <div class="prod_details_tab">
        <a href="#" title="header=[Add to cart] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="assest/cart.gif" alt="" title="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a>
        <a href="#" title="header=[Specials] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="assest/favs.gif" alt="" title="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a>
        <a href="#" title="header=[Gifts] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="assets/favorites.gif" alt="" title="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a>           
        <a href="details.html" class="prod_details">details</a>            
        </div>                     
    </div>
```

Everything displays correctly except that the image is not retrieved from the database
which is this line

```
    <div class="product_img"><a href="details.html"><%= link_to (image_tag camera_catalogue.product_image),camera_catalogue %></a></div>
```

Does the image in the database need to be saved with a different url. i.e. instead of 123.jpg it is saved as assets/123.jpg

or is there some other error in my code.

Help/advice greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Try to check source code of that products page at your browser. Find this <img>...</img> tag for this picture. And then check is this image url can be opened manually. Also app/assets folder if mostly made for app user interface features. If just wanna to save some object's images it is better to put this image at some custom folder at public folder of your project. Btw, there are a lot of gems that can be used for images storage. Check [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) or [carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like this

```
 <div class="product_img"><%= link_to (image_tag (camera_catalogue.product_image)),camera_catalogue %></div>
```

I guess it will work for you. You need not use 'assests/image_name'

Comment: Great, that seems to have sorted me out :)